# I need help with induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction if Chicken McNuggets are sold in quantities of 6, 9, and 20, then the largest amount that cannot be purchased is 43.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the question? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

Such problems are usually solved [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#McNugget_numbers) way. Note that if you find ways to achieve every value from $44$ to $49$, the rest follow inductively by adding multiples of $6$. We take $$44=4\times 6+20,\,45=5\times 9,\,46=6+2\times 20,\\47=3\times 9+20,\,48=8\times 6,\,49=9+2\times 20.$$

Comment: just wanted to say thanks for the link. did not know mcnugget numbers were a thing until now. nice little anecdote too.

Comment: I need to know how I can solve this problem using the inductive method.

Comment: @JaswinderSingh But this is inductive! First show $43$ is impossible, then prove by induction on $n$ that, for all integers $n\ge 7$, each of the integers from $6n+2$ to $6n+7$ inclusive is purchasable. I've shown the base case; the inductive step is just adding one $6$.